# Upload Cordova Video to AWS S3

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ionic-framework, aws-sdk

`$cordovaCamera.getPicture` gives me the File_URI for video, where as the AWS S3 putObject requires the entire data object for upload.

After scouring through several articles, I am not able to find a solution. I have tried several approaches as well.

Has anyone gotten this use-case to work? Please, please help.

This is an Ionic project that I am working on. I have tried variations with the following so far:

1. FileUpload plugin
2. AWS SDK putObject, and upload
3. Several methods of reading from the URI and creating my own data-object

Comment: @haywire - Is there a reason you took out "Thanks in advance for your help" from my original post? I am curious on why you took that sentence out.

Comment: thanks, salutations and so on don't belong in posts at least not on stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @raymond-camden ([Raymond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52160/raymond-camden)), for this solution:
Essentially, you need to read the binary data into a variable. If you
look at this post,

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/15/Cordova-Sample-Reading-a-text-file

you can see where I read a text file as text. It uses

reader.readAsText(file);

but you would want readAsBinaryString. You can see an example of this here:

blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

So basic idea is - create a FileEntry object, crreate a Reader, then read it.

See the example here: www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Go to "Reading a file by name"